# List View Command Set custom commands not loading

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, listviewcommandset

My SharePoint list is not loading the custom commands when the command set has been added as an app to SharePoint Online. The commands will load correctly if I try them in my 'Developer' site collection or in my a tenant I have setup using the developer subscription.

I have added a `console.log` to `onInit()` and that will load in the developer console.

I have tried the above after using the generator with the default command 1 and 2 setup and I get the same results.

Thank you

Comment: After adding extension in App Catalog, did you installed it in the Library/List? Just adding in App Catalog site does not fulfill the condition. We also have to install on Lists separately.

Comment: Yep I installed on the site/lists. I should of came back and answered this but the issue is due to a current on going issue found here. [Github 3705](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3705) and a workaround for the issue here [Github workaround](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3914#issuecomment-491069227) - hope this helps someone else out but for now Microsoft is working on resolving.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was due to an known issue that Microsoft is working on. You can view the issue here [Github 3705](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3705) and use the workaround until fixed found in this [github thread](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3914#issuecomment-491069227).